# Call different functions with multiple choice of items in a combobox, and print text in textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, combobox

For study reasons, as the title suggests, I would like to recall the functions by selecting the items in a combobox.

For example, if I select `Item1` in the combobox, I would like to call `function_item1()` and then display `This is function: function_item1` inside the textbox. The same if I select functions 2 and 3.

What can I do? Currently, of course, I get:
`This is function: None`

NOTE: I have not changed my code too much, I would like the logical structure to remain almost this

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x150")

combobox=ttk.Combobox(root, width = 18)
combobox.place(x=15, y=15)
combobox['value'] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
combobox.set("Select")

textbox = tk.Text(root,width=43,height=2)
textbox.place(x=15, y=50)


def all_function():

    a = b = c = None

    #function 1
    if combobox.get() == "Item 1":
        def function_item1():
            a = "function_item1"


    #function 2      
    if combobox.get() == "Item 2":
        def function_item2():
            b = "function_item2"

            
    #function 3
    if combobox.get() == "Item 3":
        def function_item3():
            c = "function_item3"

            
    #PRINT FUNCTIONS
    def print():
        text = f"This is function: {a or b or c}"
        textbox.insert(tk.END, text)

    print()

button2 = Button(root, text="Print", command = all_function)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=15, y=100)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the functions. The current _logical structure_ is not so good, so it is better to change that too

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria I would like it to print some text (a, b or c in relation to the combobox selection) in the textbox. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: We also would want to know a purpose for this function, are these functions for each item supposed to return something?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria The function_item1 () function supplies the text a = "function_item1". The function_item2 () function returns a = "function_item2". The function_item3 () function returns a = "function_item3". So I would like to print these in the text box in relation to the choice in the combobox

Comment: Yes I can see that, but I am asking what is the real implementation of this. This is obviously just as example that you want to implement onto someother _big thing_ right? What is the purpose of these functions there? Is it just to return a single piece of text?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Yes, it is just an example that I want to implement on other things. After figuring out how to do this, I will implement other more serious things. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is not to create alot of functions and pollute the namespace, rather just create the required functions and put it all inside a main function. This way you will avoid the extra function `print`, that you just defined.

**Method 1:**

```
def function_item1():
    return "function_item1"
def function_item2():
    return "function_item2"
def function_item3():
    return "function_item3"

def all_function():
    if combobox.get() == 'Item 1':
        text = function_item1()
    elif combobox.get() == 'Item 2':
        text = function_item2()
    else:
        text = function_item3()

    textbox.insert('end',text)
```

**Method 2:**
But a more professional way is to not create functions for these *simple* stuff like just assigning value to a piece of string that you want to use later, rather you can just avoid functions itself.

```
def all_function():
    if combobox.get() == 'Item 1':
        text = "function_item1"
    elif combobox.get() == 'Item 2':
        text = "function_item2"
    else:
        text = "function_item3"

    textbox.insert('end',text)
```

**Method 3:**
Another way is to use a dictionary to store the value for the each item in combobox:

```
def all_function():
    mapper = {
        'Item 1': "function_item1",
        'Item 2': "function_item2",
        'Item 3': "function_item3",
    }

    text = mapper.get(combobox.get(), 'None')

    textbox.insert('end',text)
```

And of course this can also be used in conjecture with having different function. This case is if you have to have to do something more than just returning a piece of text.

```
def function_item1():
    # Any big stuff you want to process on the text to be returned
    return "function_item1"
def function_item2():
    return "function_item2"
def function_item3():
    return "function_item3"

def all_function():

    mapper = {
        'Item 1': function_item1(),
        'Item 2': function_item2(),
        'Item 3': function_item3(),
    }
    text = mapper.get(combobox.get(), 'None')
    textbox.insert('end',text)
```

Though note, if you want to execute a function that will do certain activity, then you should remove the `()` to not call the function while the dictionary is made itself.

---

There are many reasons why your code did not work:

1. The first reason is that, you are creating functions but you are not executing them.
2. The next being, even if you execute the function, you will also have to globalize the variable because the functions are nested functions and `a` or `b` or `c` is not expected to be used outside their respective function.
3. Now even if you globalize `a`,`b` and `c`, still it will be `None` inside `print` because `a`,`b`, and `c` used inside the scope of `print` will be the local one created(which is `None`), so you will have to let it know to use the global one with `global a,b,c` OR you will have to move `a = b = c = None` to outside the function and then you can avoid saying `global a` inside `print`.
4. Then after that, saying `a or b or c` is wrong, as it will evaluate the expression and return a `True` or `False`. So if you want to show either of the 3 texts when an item is selected, you will have to name everything into a same variable name instead of `a,b,c` like `text` and insert that.
5. Also don't overwrite inbuilt function names like `print`, with your own version, name it something different.

So because of these reasons, we have to change your structure to make it usable. But if you want to see the working version of your code, which I would recommend not to use, is:

```
text = None # Solution to reason 3 and 4
def all_function():
    #function 1
    if combobox.get() == "Item 1":
        def function_item1():
            global text # Solution to reason 2
            text = "function_item1"

        function_item1() # Solution to reason 1

    #function 2      
    if combobox.get() == "Item 2":
        def function_item2():
            global text
            text = "function_item2"

        function_item2()
            
    #function 3
    if combobox.get() == "Item 3":
        def function_item3():
            global text
            text = "function_item3"

        function_item3()
            
    #PRINT FUNCTIONS
    def show(): # Solution to reason 5
        final_text = f"This is function: {text}" # Solution to reason 4
        textbox.insert(tk.END, final_text)

    show()
```

Comment: Give me a few minutes to try your codes. Meanwhile, out of curiosity, can you also add the solution of the code that I had written? (I know, my code wasn't very professional, but I'm curious why it didn't work correctly)

Comment: I've taken a look at all your methods and they are great. Thank you for your kindness. However I needed a solution with logic similar to my code To my code, if for each function you simply write print (a) or print (b) or print (c), it prints correctly in the python console. So while unprofessional, my code works. Not only the part to print in the textbox works thanks to the explanations you kindly said. Could you please show me a solution for my initial code too? (despite not being very professional). After that I will vote for you and immediately accept your answer.

Comment: @Jas_99 I have already added that in, but recommend not to use it.

Comment: It was just out of my curiosity, considering it was the code of the initial question. Ok now I understand. I will not use it. You have been very kind to suggest me various different solutions. I really appreciate your kindness and your skills as a programmer. I am starting out in Python. Yours was a good answer, very complete and interesting for future readers as well. Thanks again. Vote and accept